# AWS IAM role is not being destroyed when a stack is deleted

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

As part of a stack, I'm creating an IAM role for a Lambda and two nested stacks:

```
public class TestStack : Stack
{

   public TestStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
   {
        AddRole();

        new NestedStack1(this, "nested-stack1");
        new NestedStack2(this, "nested-stack2");
   }

   private void AddRole()
   {
       var role = new Role(this, "test-role", new RoleProps
       {
           AssumedBy = new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
           ManagedPolicies = new IManagedPolicy[]
           {
               ManagedPolicy.FromAwsManagedPolicyName("service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole")
           },
           RoleName = "test-role"
       });

       role.ApplyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
   }
}
```

In both nested stacks, I resolve the IAM role via

`Role.FromRoleArn(this, "test-role", $"arn:aws:iam::{Account}:role/test-role")`

The reason I had to do this is to avoid a circular dependency issue. The lambda is created in one of the nested stacks, and its role is set to the resolved role above. This code works, but I'm facing a small problem with the removal policy for the role. When I delete `TestStack` in the AWS UI, the deletion of the role fails which then fails stack deletion. It seems `RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` is not working as expected.

How would I go about automatically removing the role when CDK is destroyed?

**UPDATE:** I see the following status reason in CF Events tab:

> Cannot delete entity, must delete policies first. (Service:
> AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code:
> DeleteConflict;

Comment: How does it fail? Is there an error?

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question with error details.

Comment: Right, you cannot delete a role while it is being used in lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem with CDK when I try to destroy my ELB using "RemovalPolicy.DESTROY". But it got resolved when I added "deletion_protection=False" which might work for you.